# XSLT to compare same nodeset A in 2 files and report specified nodes X,Y, Z where A differs

Tags: xslt-1.0, diff, record, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I want to compare 2 XML files made up of records which each contain an ID field.

File 1 is the raw data input, file 2 is the cleaned up version. I want to do a basic QA on the cleaning process.

Where there's any difference between the files in terms of

- specific ID values that are in file 1 but not in file 2 (or vice versa)
- multiple instances of ID values in either file (1 or 2)

...I want to report a couple of other nodes X, Y, Z from the offending "records" that contain the additional/missing/multiple IDs, to see why (and if) those records were cleaned going from file 1 to file 2.

I get this conceptually, my main question is how to write

1. the references to the separate input files;
2. the if statement(s).

XSLT 1.0 preferred.